# error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001' near line 0: newline in field name `#padding'

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, mono

I was try to install mono using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-*
```

I closed the terminal while it was installing. I restarted the install, and I got the error message:

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I so far tried running these commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

I am now getting the following error message:

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I then used `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but now i am getting the following error:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001' near line 0: newline in field name `#padding'"**
```

I also tried `cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates && rm -rf 0045` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` , but that was no use.

how do i fix this one?

Comment: Just curious: if the file is named `0001`, why would you do `rm 0045`? O.o

Comment: @Whaaaaaat  how can you fix?

Comment: @muru if tried with 0001 then i got error like "rm: cannot remove `0001': Permission denied".

Comment: I have edit permissions on this site.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat ok you just tell me that how can i solve this error?

Comment: First off, don't delete files unless you are absolutely sure that you know what it does and how to recover if it's important.

Comment: ok i wont delete.then?

Comment: If you want to delete file in /var/lib/dpkg/updates you need root grant, so run rm command with sudo. Be careful, especially if you use -rf. If you mess up, you may also remove all !!!

Answer (score 33):

Make a backup and remove the `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001` via

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001 /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001.X
```

After that

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 5):

here's how i fixed this problem ..
first i removed the whole updates directory ..

```
rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/updates
```

after that create a new updates directory

```
mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/updates
```

and finally

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

**cleans the apt-get job**

```
 sudo apt-get clean
```

**updates package lists**

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install <whatever package>
```

should get you right

and as @Whaaaaat said you shouldn't delete anything unless you are absolutely sure what it is and what it does, especially if bash is telling you 'you need root permission to even do it'

Comment: I suffered the exact same dpkg error and this does not help anything to solve it.  -1.